# Android studio/Kotlin file: Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.myapplication.ZadatakKt

Tags: android, kotlin

Im trying to use android studio and write kotlin class/file.
This is the code

```
package com.example.myapplication

fun main(){
    println("Hello world")
}
```

as you can see the code isnt complicated or anything so i doubt that thats the problem.

when i run it i get error:

**Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.myapplication.ZadatakKt
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.myapplication.ZadatakKt**

Please help how do i fix it and thanks in advance.

I tried going into the settings to see if Kotlin was up to date and its at the newest stable version.
Idk if I should configure something in the setting or somwhere so please help.

Comment: What type of project did you initialize in Android Studio? It seems from the code you have shared that there is no class definition.